# How large the error ball of $\|x\| $is, when using the Lyapunov function $x^\top Px$?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I would like to know how large the error ball of $\|x\|$ is when using the Lyapunov function $x^\top Px$:

**Assumption:** I have an almost linear closed-loop system $\dot{x}=(A-BK)x+\epsilon(x)$ with small perturbation $\epsilon$. Suppose I've defined *the Lyapunov function $V=x^\top Px$ and managed to show $W=\sqrt{V}< b_{error}$ using [the Comparison lemma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFxmrxBbQug). Thus now we know $\sqrt{x^\top Px}< b_{error}$.

*Note that $P$ is positive definite satisfying the Riccati equation of the linear closed-loop system $A-BK$.

**Question:** What I want to know is the error ball of $\|x\|$, not $\sqrt{x^\top Px}$. How can I go to the error ball of $\|x\|$ from $b_{error}$?

I guess, the decomposition $P=\Lambda^\top \Lambda$ and $w=\Lambda x$ would work: $\sqrt{x^\top Px}$= $\sqrt{w^\top w}=\|w\|<b_{error}$, meaning $\|\Lambda^{-1}x\|<b_{error}$. If I can somehow lower bound this inequality by |x|, like $c\|x\|<\|\Lambda^{-1}x\|<b_{error}$, I can prove |x| converges to $b_{error}/c$. But I'm not sure what can be $c$.

Comment: Just to confirm, you've already applied linear state feedback right with $u = -Kx$? If so, then isn't $\epsilon$ just a function of $x$? Or is this another input?

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Thank you. Actually, the control input is $u=-Kx - \hat{f}(x,u)$ to the system $ \dot{x}=Ax+Bu+f$ where the $\hat{f}(x,u)$ is the Deep Neural Network-model of unknown dynamics $f$ as a feedback cancellation term. Since DNN cannot be the perfect copy of the $f$, the estimation error $\epsilon$ happens. But this notation seems not to affect the answer to this question

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Moreover, the reason why I'm able to define $V$ as a function only of $x$ is that I can upper bound $\hat{f}$ only by $x$ term in the proof process, which we applied the Comparison Lemma.

Comment: @SpaceTAKA Are you sure this input is well defined? Looks like an algebraic loop to me, how do you resolve this loop?

Comment: @SampleTime Thank you. I changed the statement to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Hi, everyone! Thank you for your comments, I finally made it to prove! Thx so much